# Locate very next comma to a given substring within string

Tags: mysql

I have string `{"abc":"dds","def":null,"ghi":fgi"}` stored with in a field in database. how can I find very next comma after "def" string?

Actually I have such list of string e.g

```
{"abc":"dds","def":null,"ghi":"fgi"}
{"abc":"123","def":234,"ghi":"fgd"}
{"abc":"133-d","def":"asd-123","ghi":"fgi"}
.....
```

I need to remove all occurences of "def" with value i.e I need the result as

```
{"abc":"dds","ghi":"fgi"}
{"abc":"123","ghi":"fgd"}
{"abc":"133-d","ghi":"fgi"}
```

Comment: what is the result you want?

Comment: What is your mysql version? You do realize that this is a JSON right?

Comment: 5.5.47, Yes this json stored as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you a working example based on your given data.

```
SET @str := '{"abc":"133-d","def":"asd-123","ghi":"fgi"}';
```

---

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
            @str
            FROM
                1 FOR LOCATE('def' ,@str) - 2
        ),
        SUBSTRING(
            @str
            FROM (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str)))) FOR (LENGTH(@str) + 1 - (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str)))))
        )
    ) AS newJson;
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/157f5/3/1)

**Explanation:**

`Explanation based on this string '{"abc":"dds","def":null,"ghi":fgi"}'`

---

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str   FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('def' ,@str) - 2 );
Result#1: {"abc":"dds",

SELECT (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str))));
Result#2: 25 // Location of the comma next to 'def':value

SELECT (LENGTH(@str) + 1 - (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str)))));
Result#3: 11 // Length of the rest of the string after that very comma

Now get the SUBSTRING(@str FROM position 25 to Result#3 )

It will return 
Result #4: "ghi":fgi"}
```

Now concat result#1 and result#4 to get the full desired string that is {"abc":"dds","ghi":fgi"}

**Note:** Doing this job in Application level will definitely give you more flexibility.

---

**Edit:**

---

You may create a function named `getNewJsonString` and use it where you require.

```
DELIMITER $

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getNewJsonString$
CREATE FUNCTION getNewJsonString(inputStr VARCHAR(300))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE returnString VARCHAR(255);

SET @str := inputStr;
SET returnString := (SELECT
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(
            @str
            FROM
                1 FOR LOCATE('def' ,@str) - 2
        ),
        SUBSTRING(
            @str
            FROM (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str)))) FOR (LENGTH(@str) + 1 - (LOCATE('def' ,@str) + LOCATE(',',SUBSTRING(@str,LOCATE('def' ,@str)))))
        )
    ))  ;

RETURN returnString;

END$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Sample function Call:**

```
SELECT getNewJsonString('{"abc":"dds","def":null,"ghi":"fgi"}');
```

**Output:**

`{"abc":"dds","ghi":"fgi"}`

Comment: better create a `function` and `pass your main string one by one` from the list and get the `returned result` and `update thereby in the database`. @Abs

Comment: Created a sample function. Please check in the `Edit` section. @Abs